# Множественные ветвления if в python

Tags: python, if

Всем привет!
Заранее, прошу прощения если не туда попал, я только учусь. :-)
В настоящий момент прохожу онлайн курс в Яндекс практикуме. Читаю условия решаю задачи.
И вот на моем пути повстречалась следующая задача:

Задача 2
Готовим завтрак. В зависимости от наличия продуктов есть разные варианты меню:
Если есть молоко (milk) и хлопья (cereals) — можно позавтракать хлопьями с молоком.
Если есть яйца (eggs) — на завтрак будет яичница.
Если есть молоко и яйца — можно сотворить омлет.
Есть и более бюджетные варианты: попить молока, погрызть сухих хлопьев или вовсе не завтракать.
Прочтите код, отследите логику ветвления.
Подставьте вместо многоточия такой логический оператор, с которым программа будет работать корректно.

```
# Продуктов маловато:
milk = not True       # Молоко "НЕ есть".
cereals = True        # Хлопья есть.
eggs = False          # Яиц нет.

# Вставьте логический оператор вместо многоточия.
# Решите, нужно ли расставить скобки.

if milk and cereals or eggs:
    if eggs:
        if milk:
            breakfast = "- омлет"
        else:
            breakfast = "- яичница"
    else:
        breakfast = "- хлопья с молоком"
else:
    if milk:
        breakfast = "- стакан молока"
    elif cereals:
        breakfast = "можно погрызть сухих хлопьев"
    else:
        breakfast = "ничего не будет: разгрузочный день"

print("Сегодня на завтрак", breakfast)
```

Саму задачу решил быстро, путем перебора or и and.
Но, интересно понять, как же этот код работает.
Мне не понятно, выражение "if milk and cereals or eggs:" Возвращает что-то одно, правду или ложь.
Как python делает выбор между аж шести вариантами? Как он понимает, что если нужно выбрать из if - блока правды ветку лжи?

Comment: Если вы знаете, как работает булева алгебра (сочетания AND, OR и т.д.), то Python работатет по той же логике - отличий нет. Если не знаете - почитайте (особенно про приоритет операторов), тут всё не описать будет. Коротко: `if milk and cereals or eggs` = `if (milk and cereals) or eggs` - Правда будет если либо И молоко И Хлопья есть, ИЛИ если Яйца есть. И синтаксис и в русском важен - не только в Python => "ложь", "лжи":-)

Comment: @Сергей, в этом конкретном примере отличий нет. Python расширяет `or` и `and` на произвольные объекты. `3 or 5` -> `3`, `3 and 5` -> `5`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, мда, "не знал, да ещё и забыл", спасибо. Но к вычислению логических значений, когда используются `True` и `False` в условиях это как может относиться?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, хотел спросить зачем вообще такое нужно, но вижу, что `c = a and b` работает в среднем быстрее, чем `c = a if a>b else b`. Да и короче запись.

Comment: @Сергей, я не знаю зачем нужно. С моей точки зрения, это больше усложняет язык чем даёт какие-то возможности.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запускаем в голове интерпретатор. Начальные значения:

```
milk = False
cereals = True
eggs = False
```

Как вычислить выражение для ингредиентов?

```
milk and cereals or eggs
```

расставляем скобки (в этом примере это не важно, в других может повлиять):

```
(milk and cereals) or eggs
```

подставляем значения:

```
(False and True) or False
```

вычисляем скобки (нужна таблица истинности для `and`):

```
False or False
```

вычисляем выражение (нужна таблица истинности для `or`):

```
False
```

Значит мы попали в ветку `else`:

```
    if milk:
        breakfast = "- стакан молока"
    elif cereals:
        breakfast = "можно погрызть сухих хлопьев"
    else:
        breakfast = "ничего не будет: разгрузочный день"
```

`milk` - ложь, пропускаем `if`. Проверяем `elif`: `cereals` - истина, выполняем "погрызть", покидаем все условные операторы.

Answer (score 0):

```
if milk and cereals or eggs:
```

Можно переписать так:

```
Если (Молока И хлопья) ИЛИ яйца
```

И и ИЛИ имеют разный приоритет(как умножение и сложение в математике). И имеет приоритет выше, чем ИЛИ, поэтому выполняется раньше.

Операция И возвращает ИСТИНУ только тогда, когда оба операнда являются ИСТИННОЙ
Операция ИЛИ возвращает ИСТИНУ, когда хотя бы один операнд является ИСТИННОЙ

Почитайте про алгебру логики: она является частью необходимой базы

Answer (score -3):

```
if milk and cerals or eggs
```

сокращение от

```
if milk==true and cerals==true or eggs==true:
```

milk, cerals, eggs - логические переменные которые принимают значение True или False, соответственно.

Comment: Ваше объяснение неверно: Питон отлично работает с выражениями `'пиво' and 'рыба'` -> `' рыба'` и `'пиво' or 'рыба'` -> `'пиво'`.